# How to add trait to existing class in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How to make this code work, add trait/mixing to existing built-in class, like String? I guess trait should be used as mixins are deprecated?

```
trait StringExtensions {
  def isEmpty() {
    this.size() == 0
  }
}

String.someMagic(StringExtensions)

println("Hello".isEmpty())
```

Comment: https://blog.mrhaki.com/2014/05/groovy-goodness-implementing-traits-at.html?m=1

Comment: @tim_yates thanks, but this blog post doesn't explain how to add it to built in classes like String

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have for classes like `String` or other pre-compiled classes is to use runtime traits.

```
def s = "someString".withTraits StringExtensions
println( s.isEmpty() )
```

What you probably are looking for is [Extension Modules](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extending_existing_classes).  For that it would something like this:

```
class StringExtensions {
   static boolean isEmpty( String self ) {
       self.length() == 0
   }
}
```

Then you have to do register an extension file on the class path under `META-INF/groovy/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule`.  So add this to your resources folder with the following content:

```
moduleName=String Extensions
moduleVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
extensionClasses=com.myextensions.StringExtensions
```

Extension Modules are compatible with type checking unlike things like Categories or using runtime Traits.

Comment: Seems like ther's one more way to do it `String.metaClass.isEmpty = { -> delegate.size() == 0 }`

Comment: Yes that is the original way to augment instance methods, but it's really old and there are better options with these more modern methods.  It's also only a runtime thing so performance will take a hit invoking them, no type checking, and your IDE won't help you with autocomplete and it'll flag it as an unknown method.  Extension Modules does the same thing, but your IDE will recognize it.